# How can i parse JSON from URL on Android and display it in listview

Tags: android, json

1. My **JSON** data looks like this:(**JSON** data has more data but I have put only a chunk of data here).

   ```
    {
    "items": [
       {
         "id": 15,
     "batchId": 0,
    "dateCreated": "2016-05-29T19:03:37Z",
    "description": "sdfdsf",
    "ean": 0,
    "expDate": "1990-12-22T00:00:00Z",
    "itemActive": true,
    "itemAlternateNames": [
     {
     "class": "com.canre.domain.ItemAlternateName",
     "id": 16,
     "dateCreated": "2016-05-29T19:03:37Z",
     "district": null,
     "itemMaster": {
       "_ref": "../..",
       "class": "com.canre.domain.ItemMaster"
     },
     "itemName": "Ryan Reynolds",
     "language": null,
     "lastUpdated": "2016-05-29T19:03:37Z",
     "state": null
      }
     ],
   ```

   2.This is my **MainActivity class**.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   ListView listView;
   ItemsAdapter adapter;
   ArrayList<Items> itemsArrayList;
   DBHandler dbHandler;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
   Button btnHit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHit);
   dbHandler=new DBHandler(this);
   NetworkUtils utils = new NetworkUtils(MainActivity.this);
   if(dbHandler.getItemsCount() == 0 && utils.isConnectingToInternet())
   {
       new DataFetcherTask().execute();
   }
   else
   {
       ArrayList<Items> itemsArrayList = dbHandler.getAllItems();
       adapter=new ItemsAdapter(MainActivity.this,itemsArrayList);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    }

   private class DataFetcherTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       String serverData=null;

       String dataUrl =   "my url";
       String dataUrlParameters = "Id:"+"123"+"Updated:"+"dd/mm/yyy";
       URL url;
       HttpURLConnection connection = null;
       try {
   // Create connection
   url = new URL(dataUrl);
   connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
   connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(dataUrlParameters.getBytes().length));
           connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
           connection.setUseCaches(false);
           connection.setDoInput(true);
           connection.setDoOutput(true);
   // Send request
   DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
   connection.getOutputStream());
   wr.writeBytes(dataUrlParameters);
           wr.flush();
           wr.close();
   // Get Response
   InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();                        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
           String line;
           StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
           while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
               response.append(line);
               response.append('\r');
           }
           rd.close();
           String responseStr = response.toString();
           Log.d("Server response", responseStr);

       } catch (Exception e) {

           e.printStackTrace();

       } finally {

           if (connection != null) {
               connection.disconnect();
           }
       }
       return null;
   }
   protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid){
       super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
       ArrayList<Items> itemsArrayList=dbHandler.getAllItems();
       adapter=new ItemsAdapter(MainActivity.this,itemsArrayList);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
   }
   }
   ```

When I run the project it throws **fileNotFound** exception and sometimes runs without errors but noting is displayed on my **ListView**....